# How can I resolve 'node module error' when deploying a project to Vercel?

Tags: typescript, deployment, node-modules, vercel, next.js13

I'm using world-countries, and when deploying in vercel it comes an error that says that a ';' is missing in the index.d.ts file of world-countries which is in the node_module directory.

this is what vercel gives me:

Failed to compile.
./node_modules/world-countries/index.d.ts:45:37
Type error: ';' expected.
43 |   translations: { [languageCode: string]: OfficialAndCommon }
44 |   latlng: [number, number]

> 45 |   demonyms: { [languageCode: string]?: Demonyms } (this is the line that needs to be fixed)
> |                                     ^
> 46 |   landlocked: boolean
> 47 |   borders: string[]
> 48 |   area: number

what I try was deleting the '?' and the issue went away in the file but vercel doesnt take it.
I tried using another way to put it: demonym: string which is the previous way it was done
I tried using ways to ignore it

nothing is working

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the `?` will fix it, but Vercel will not take the modified version you have in your local, because Vercel will do an `npm install`.

Looks like this issue will be fixed in the next version of `world-countries` you can see it in [this PR](https://github.com/mledoze/countries/commit/3100acd7f5fdcf458ea3279800608ea96ddbb6d0)

You have 2 options:

### Option 1

Wait for the new version of world-countries and do a `npm install world-countries@latest`

### Option 2

Overwrite the `index.d.ts` of `world-countries`, how?

***Step 1 Create your own index.d.ts file***

- Create a folder `types`, inside create a folder `world-countries`
- Copy over the `index.d.ts` from `./node_modules/world-countries`
  [image]
- Remove the `?`  [image]

***Step 2 Tell Typescript to use it instead of the one the package has***

- In your `tsconfig.json` add a new path:

```
"world-countries": [
    "./types/world-countries/index.d.ts"
 ],
```

- Should look like this: 
  [image]

to test it i recommend deleting `node_modules` then doing a clean `npm install` then `npm run build`.